# PCIe Gen3 x4 SSD disk combatible on PCIe x8 old motherboard slot?

Tags: ssd, pci-express

Can you tell me if I can use a PCIe Gen3 x4 SSD disk (Intel SSDPEDMW400G4R5) in a 8 years old motherboard with a PCIe x8 (Supermicro PDSMA+) slot? There will be any speed caps? Like a SATA III disk on SATA II slot?

Comment: PCIe is backwards compatible.  A faster device will run at the slower speeds.  So a PCIe x8 device will run at PCIe x4 speeds if plugged into a PCie x4 slot.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ramhound! So it will fit but with a speed cap. Answer it so i can accept it...

Comment: Feel free to self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ramhound noticed the SSD will be compatible with the slot but it will have a speed decrease